# Umbraco log DependencyHandler error

Tags: logging, umbraco, client-dependency

My Umbraco log is filling up quickly with messages like the following one:

```
At /xx/DependencyHandler.axd/f88c46d6fcf7ee6b39a67236364e7300/158/js (Referred by: http://www.mysite.com/xx/)
```

It happens to all the paths, and also happens in js and css.
I cannot reproduce it in my local, but I have this error around 10 times per minute in the actual server.

Any idea about how to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just for future: http://our.umbraco.org/forum/core/41-feedback/10522-DependencyHandleraxd-fails-to-load

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to setup an HTTP handler, to deal with these requests: https://github.com/Shandem/ClientDependency/wiki/Configuration